# How to make radiobutton width the same for different width columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble making the radio button area (input-group-addon) the same size in col-sm-4 and col-sm-6 columns. I looked at some other answers where people used min-width and this solution did not work for me. I would like a uniform width for my radio button controls. Here is a visual example. My first radiobutton (input-group-addon) is wider than the second input-groups    [imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8TpJ.jpg)

```css
.form-control {
  width: 150px;
}

.radio-width {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon radio-width">
          <span class="control-label">
            <input type="radio" name="anyDate" value="anyDate"> 
          </span> 
        </span>
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">          
        </div>                            
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon radio-width">
          <span class="control-label">
            <input type="radio" name="dateRange" value="dateRange"> 
          </span> 
        </span>
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">      
        </div>                            
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20504/

Comment: Not sure what you want, the actual radio circle and text box square should be the same size? Or the box containing them? If the latter, you can just style all inputs with the desired width: input {width:50%;}

Comment: Yes, even though the second input group addon will be really wide. I want the radiobutton parts to be the same width.

Comment: @RachelS I have updated to your solution, you are welcome to answer and I'll be happy to delete mine.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my problem. You can see 'any date' radio button is wider.        http://imgur.com/YDPi6qw

Comment: Yes you can see that the first radio button area (input-group-addon) is not the same width as the second one. i want them to be the same width. The input-groups are not the same size. This makes using % impossible. I tried her input % and it did not resolve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making a bit of confusion with input-group-addon element.
An [input-group-addon](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/) should be coded as follows:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Therefore your code should be like:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"> <!-- don't need radio-width -->
        <input type="radio" name="anyDate" value="anyDate"> 
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-full">      
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20514/).